# TS2322: Type '* | *' is not assignable to type '* & *'. Как тип 'test1' | 'test2' превратить в 'test1' & 'test2'?

Tags: typescript

Есть конструктор класса

```
type Params = { social?: Social; seo?: SEO };

class Class {
  public seo?: SEO;
  public social?: Social;

  constructor(params: ParamsCreating) {
    const { title, content, dateTime, id, ...extra } = params;
    if (extra) {
      Object.keys(extra).forEach((key: keyof Params) => {
        this[key] = extra[key];
        ^----
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Компилятор выводит вот такую ошибку:

> TS2322: Type 'Social | SEO' is not assignable to type 'Social & SEO'.   Type 'Social' is not assignable to type 'Social & SEO'.     Property 'tags' is missing in type 'Social' but required in type 'SEO'.

Если я вручную перепишу вот так:

```
type Params = { social?: Social; seo?: SEO };

class Class {
  public seo?: SEO;
  public social?: Social;

  constructor(params: ParamsCreating) {
    const { title, content, dateTime, id, ...extra } = params;
    if (extra) {
      Object.keys(extra).forEach((key: 'seo' & 'social') => {
        this[key] = extra[key];
      });
    }
  }
}
```

То проходит без ошибок.

Как переписать данный код, чтобы заменить конструкцию `key: 'seo' & 'social'` на что-то более гибкое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

иногда, полезно просто взять и заткнуть TS

```
Object.keys(extra).forEach(key => {
    // @ts-ignore
    this[key] = extra[key]
})
```

но в вашем случае, вместо условия и перебора, логичнее и проще использовать

```
Object.assign(this, extra)
```

[там](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gYwJYEMA2UC8UUDsQBQoksAogPJY74EFK7AQBOAZigtAIpQDeBUAqAHohUALQAaMQQC+BBGhQBnJVG59BUMAFcARmiQIoSiHAD8ALjLkA3P0E79h44lRpLsV+jv2BCOLhKwEzaCMBwTAAUYChMKAC2SlacAHQAJDFxiQCUvL6aUP6BwLxQwEjAaBAShQGMDDUAJiiMACpI8dVQSI01Kf0QAB7BKFAyVJkJSnYFgkgsUJFDI7kaswUi4mJQ5ABK+es7ugBWEGEpykpIAOa4kcAAFkhKNctx2Qfrm2Lbe5+zm3IJzOwBSAGsICAlEthu8UiwIqR2A9IhCQFgAHx5Q6aTa40QAAWASjEN1wEQg-w2ok0j2eAG00QBdKhvFCMyFMqn4sYfQ5yTRyOS4BIQJQxDhqbGCb6-faaIZgCIlYjQDKxKZUbgAMmls3KlQgVjwIBm6yK9WAxvwZtmzTaHSN1FNVJ61pdgvysp28plokVyu6DGYbEl6qyqmWEFwjVU6i9NMEBqq7ttwkTfjq0atzrTeME9og7U6qYTBTdubLQqAA) немного кода

Comment: Спасибо большое!